# Continuous $f\colon(0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$ that is continuos but not Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, cauchy-sequences

I'm trying to think of a function $f\colon (0,1)\to R$ which is continuous in $\mathbb R$ but is not Cauchy in $\mathbb R$. I think I'm picturing what it needs to look like, but can't think of a function that fits the area. I was thinking a function that has a vertical asymptote at $0$ and $1$ ? Maybe $\arcsin(x)$?

Comment: What is the definition of "Cauchy" for a function?

Comment: I suppose it would be if there was an N where for all n,m > N, there is an epsilon where the distance between f(n) and f(m) is less than epsilon.

Comment: This is the definition of a sequence being Cauchy. There isn't any n or m in your statement above, so that doesn't really fit.

My guess is "Cauchy" for a function means "Cauchy continuous"  meaning if you apply f to all the elements of a Cauchy sequence, you'll still end up with a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: @Andrew, I think you've scrambled things up a bit there. but I think ur trying to get at the definition of uniform continuity

Comment: In the answers provided below, haven't you got any answer to your Question? It seems so because you haven't accepted any !

Answer (score 0):

You'll want a function that wiggles around a lot, increasingly higher and more frequently as you approach some point (0 is likely easiest). Then you can make the $f(x_i)$ arbitrarily far apart, even though the $x_i$ get close to each other (and 0).

Keep in mind if you want to show a function is **not** Cauchy continuous, you simply have to find an example when it doesn't hold. That means you get to pick the Cauchy sequence.

Comment: like f(x) = x^3?

Comment: _"a function that **wiggles around a lot**, **increasingly higher** and **more frequently** as you approach some point"_

Comment: How obvious is this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are looking for a function that is continuous on $(0,1)$ but it fails to send all Cauchy sequences to Cauchy sequences (which is also called Uniformly continuous) in $(0,1)$ .

In that case simply consider $f: (0,1) \to \Bbb R$ defined by,  $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ . It's continuous on $(0,1)$.

I give 2 arguments :

1. Then consider the Cauchy sequence $\{\frac{1}{n} \}_{n=1}^\infty$ . It's image is simply, $\{n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ a diverging sequence and hence not Cauchy.
2. Or you can simply consider the Continuous extension theorem, which tells that $f$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,1)$ iff $f$ can be extended continuously to the boundary points of the interval i.e.  at $x =0 $ and $x=1$ . But it is not continuous at $x=0$ !